# How to place 0 after one repeated row in a particular column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a select query which gives me required result. This is what I am getting the data from query:

```
RXID|   NoOfRx|     DrName          |HospitalName           |SBOID
----|---------|---------------------|-----------------------|-------------
82  |   2     |dr abcdefgh kjk      |sdmh hospital          |56183
82  |   2     |dr abcdefgh kjk      |sdmh hospital          |56183
82  |   2     |dr abcdefgh kjk      |sdmh hospital          |56183
82  |   2     |dr abcdefgh kjk      |sdmh hospital          |56183
82  |   2     |dr abcdefgh kjk      |sdmh hospital          |56183
83  |   1     |dr kkkk jjjj         |nakaoana hospital      |56183
152 |   1     |dr dskhjgjhgjhhghjghg|sms hospital, jaireur  |56183
```

This is what I want :

```
RXID|   NoOfRx|     DrName          |HospitalName           |SBOID
----|---------|---------------------|-----------------------|-------------
82  |   2     |dr abcdefgh kjk      |sdmh hospital          |56183
82  |   0     |dr abcdefgh kjk      |sdmh hospital          |56183
82  |   0     |dr abcdefgh kjk      |sdmh hospital          |56183
82  |   0     |dr abcdefgh kjk      |sdmh hospital          |56183
82  |   0     |dr abcdefgh kjk      |sdmh hospital          |56183
83  |   1     |dr kkkk jjjj         |nakaoana hospital      |56183
152 |   1     |dr dskhjgjhgjhhghjghg|sms hospital, jaireur  |56183
```

It should be such that for every duplicate `RXID`, the rest of `NoOfRx` Column will be zero.How do I do that? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1) Identify the duplicates 2) do a row_number 3) mark as 0 where row_number > 1

Comment: Just a thought but would an aggregation function with 'group by' not be better here as it would return only one line instead of manipulated ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but, probably something like:

```
SELECT RXID,
       CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RXID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)/*I can see no unique ID in your table*/) WHEN 1 THEN NoOfRx ELSE 0 END AS NoOfRx
       DrName,
       HospitalName,
       SBOID
FROM YourTable;
```

The row that has the value of `NoOfRx` will be **random**, as there is no unique key which can be used to create an order.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
;WITH CTE AS
( 
    SELECT 82 AS RXID ,   2     AS NoOfRx,'dr abcdefgh kjk' AS DrName,'sdmh hospital' AS HospitalName,56183 AS SBOID
    UNION ALL SELECT 82  ,   2     ,'dr abcdefgh kjk'      ,'sdmh hospital',          56183
    UNION ALL SELECT 82  ,   2     ,'dr abcdefgh kjk'      ,'sdmh hospital',          56183
    UNION ALL SELECT 82  ,   2     ,'dr abcdefgh kjk'      ,'sdmh hospital',          56183
    UNION ALL SELECT 82  ,   2     ,'dr abcdefgh kjk'      ,'sdmh hospital',          56183
    UNION ALL SELECT 83  ,   1     ,'dr kkkk jjjj'         ,'nakaoana hospital',      56183
    UNION ALL SELECT 152 ,   1     ,'dr dskhjgjhgjhhghjghg','sms hospital,jaireur',56183
)
SELECT RXID
,CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NoOfRx ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) WHEN 1 THEN NoOfRx ELSE 0 END AS NoOfRx
,DrName,HospitalName,SBOID
FROM CTE
```

Comment: That really helped. Thanks mate for the answer.